# How to update GameplayKit entities and components in a SceneKit Game

Tags: scenekit, gameplay-kit

I have a SceneKit game that I'm attempting to integrate with GameplayKit.

In order for GameplayKit to work, I need to update my components and entities by calling their `updateWithDeltaTime(seconds:)` method.

In the SpriteKit/GameplayKit examples I've seen, this is done using the SKScene's `update` method which fires continuously with no input from the user or the developer.

It seems that in SceneKit, to achieve something similar I need to call the `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` method `renderer(renderer: updateAtTime time:)`.

However, this only fires when something in the scene is running, such as an SCNAction. But in my game, nothing is running until the user swipes.

Is there another, recommended SceneKit way to hook into some sort of run loop that runs continuously without any sort of prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, SceneKit doesn't run the animation loop unless it knows there's something animating. That can include actions, animations, or physics.

If you want the animation loop to run without any of those things going on, set the view's [`playing`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNSceneRenderer_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfp/SCNSceneRenderer/playing) property to true.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I've just had another quick scan through the SceneKit docs, and I can't find where that's documented.